# Replace text from line above in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

How can I replace the first ten characters of a line where those ten characters match a particular pattern with the first ten characters from the line above?

Edit: It wasn't clear if I was asking to replace the first ten characters where the match could appear anywhere within the line, so maybe make a note in your answer if it deals with this case (call this case B and the intended one case A?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
:%s/^\(.\{10}\)\(.*\n\)abcdefghij\(.*\)/\1\2\1\3/
```

Where 'abcdefghij' is the 10 character string on the 2nd line.

Comment: What if the pattern that you want to match is not the first 10 characters of that line? This may not work in that case.

Comment: @B Johnson the question states that the 10 characters are in the beginning of the line.

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know that vim regexes could span lines.

Comment: @Renato: depends how you parse the sentence. Could be either: "the first 10 characters of (a line matching a particular pattern)" or "(the first 10 characters of a line) matching a particular pattern"

Comment: @rampion: A "line" is merely a presentational concept. To a regex it's all the same - a sequence of characters, some of which being newline characters. Sure, there are "^" and "$" anchors, and "." does stop at newline characters, but these are convenience defaults rather than actual limitations.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work:

```
%s/^.\{10\}/\=strpart(get(getbufline("", line(".")-1), 0, ""), 0, 10)/
```

where `^.\{10\}` is your actual pattern.

```
%s/                      # substitute all lines matching…
^.\{10\}                 # your pattern
/                        # …with…
\=                       # an expression:
strpart(                 # gets the part of a string
  get(                   # gets an element of a list
    getbufline(          # gets a list of lines from the current buffer
      "", line(".")-1)   # getbufline() the line before the current line
  , 0, "")               # get() first line in buffer, default to ""
, 0, 10)                 # strpart() first ten characters
/                        # …end of substitution
```

Answer (score 3):

```
:2,$g/<pattern>/s/^.\{10}/\=strpart(getline(line(".")-1),0,10)
```

- `2,$` is our range (as the first line has no previous line)
- `g//` lets you run a command on lines that match a given pattern.
- `s/^.\{10}/` will replace the first 10 characters of a line
- `\=` lets you substitute the result of a vim expression in an `:s//`
- `line(".")` is the current line number
- `getline(line(".")-1)` is the text of the previous line
- `strpart(getline(line(".")-1),0,10)` is the first 10 characters of the previous line

For example `2,$g/frog/s/^.\{10}/\=strpart(getline(line(".")-1),0,10)` will change:

```
I like eating mangos
before frying frogs legs
I wish I had a puppy
She gave Dad a frog
```

To this:

```
I like eating mangos
I like eating frogs legs
I wish I had a puppy
I wish I had a frog
```

Answer (score 2):

If I have a complex action like that I usually record a macro using the `q` command. Something like (untested):

```
/<pattern>
qq
10x
k
10yl
j
P
n
q
```

And then repeatedy issue that macro as `@q` optionally prefixed with a count.

Answer (score 1):

You could use search and replace:

```
:7,9 s/foo/bar/c
```

This example searches from line 7 to 9 for each occurrence of 'foo', and replaces it with 'bar', asking for a confirm on each hit. If you don't want to confirm, drop the c at the end. Pick the range as you see fit and this should get you where you want

Answer (score 1):

Using only vim's motions and yanking/pasting.. Given the file contents of..

```
1234567890abcdef
qwertyuiopasdfgh
```

With the cursor on q, `10x`, file becomes:

```
1234567890abcdef
asdfgh
```

Move the cursor to the first line (using `k` will do it), then do `10yl` (yank 10 characters, right)

Then move back down one line, `j`, and paste `P` (upper case, to paste under cursor) and the file becomes:

```
1234567890abcdef
1234567890asdfgh
```

In short, starting with the cursor on q:

```
10xk10yljP
```

..which you could paste in, or assign [to a macro](http://www.oreillynet.com/mac/blog/2006/07/more_vim_save_time_with_macros_1.html)

It would be shorter if there was an obvious shortcut to paste by overwriting, but I couldn't find such a thing

One other option is an incredibly obscure looking regex search/replace..

Visual-line select the two target lines, and run the following search-and-replace:

```
:'<,'>s/\(\(.\{10\}\).*\)\n\(.\{10\}\)\(.*\)$/\1\r\2\4/
```

Basically it grabs..

- `\1` - the entire first line
- `\2` - the first 10 characters (in a nested group)
- a linebreak
- `\3` - the first ten characters of line two
- `\4` - the rest of the second line

Then it constructs the two lines as `\1\n\2\4` - complete first line, linebreak, first 10 characters of first, remainder of second